# ASP controls or normal html link in jgrowl

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jgrowl

I have been using [jgrowl](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jGrowl), can i know how to use Asp controls in jgrowl or ?? because i need to display a link in notification, when user clicks that link i need to redirect to desired page is that possible ??

Comment: How are you opening/creating the notifications?

Comment: I am opening jgrowl from code behind and mean while i tried to merge asp controls so that user click on desired button it will redirect him to desired page ! i dont know how to display that controls in jgrowl because it doesnt have any event

Comment: Unless I'm thinking of a different jgrowl project, it's just JavaScript that runs client side, it pretty much has nothing to do with the code behind (which runs server side).

Comment: yes its a javascript which runs in client side, but i need to display a link inside jgrowl is that possible :) thanks for your reply

Comment: guys help me out ! I need to display asp controls inside jgrowl notification !

Comment: You can't put ASP.NET controls inside growl notifications (at least not directly) because they live in different places.  Growl notifications are dynamically generated in the browser, ASP.NET controls live on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could get the result you are looking for, I don't know for sure which would be good enough to solve your problem, so lets try the easiest one.
I'd create a function in a regular HTML script section to wrap jGrowl's code

```
<script>
function wrapLinkLegend(url,text){
 $.jGrowl("<a href='"+text+"'>"+text+"</a>");
}
</script>
```

then from your .net code call this function... i.e.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string url="http://www.google.com";
   string linkText = "Click me!";
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                                this,
                                this.GetType(),
                                Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),//Perhaps "dummy" would be enough
                                String.Format("wrapLinkLegend('{0}','{1}');",url,linkText);
                                true);
}
```

If this is not good enough let me know and we could try a different approach

regards

Comment: Yes, I have tried the same approach to see the result :) i try your code once and i will let you know the result :) thanks